# How to catch validation error message - Nestjs Gateway Socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I have a validation pipe that checks if a user-sent JSON data is valid. Validator is working great, but I can not catch the error and then send it to the client. I know about `exeptionFactory` property in `ValidationPipe` constructor, but I still can not catch an error and it still logs in the console.

```
[Nest] 11820  - 01/07/2023, 11:12:25 PM   ERROR [WsExceptionsHandler] Bad Request Exception
BadRequestException: Bad Request Exception
```

Here is a code

```
  @SubscribeMessage(Stream.Transactions)
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  handleTransactions(
    clien: any,
    @MessageBody() data: TransactionObject,
  ) {
    let req = this.streamService.transaction(data)
    return { event: Stream.Transactions, data: req }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a filter to get the error and return some specific data. But you can do it in a couple ways: Creating a [Websocket exception filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/exception-filters) to catch the error or use the [exceptionFactory](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) you mention in your question to generate a `WsException` and catch into the filter.

The main problem (if I'm not wrong) is the pipe does not return a `WsException` but a `BadRequestException`.

So to use an exception filter, how the exception is `Bad Request`, you can use this one:

```js
@Catch(BadRequestException)
export class BadRequestExceptionsFilter extends BaseWsExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    // Here you have the exception and you can check the data
    const wsException = new WsException(exception.getResponse())
    super.catch(wsException, host);
  }
}
```

Note how this code follows the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/exception-filters#inheritance)

And now not only you can get and read the exception but also you can create a properly `WsException`.

To use this you can add `@UseFilters(BadRequestExceptionsFilter)` into your gateway.

Another way is to catch WS and HTTP exceptions and handle properly you want, something similar [to this example](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#catch-everything). The idea can be to catch the HTTP exception only to get `Bad Request` so your desired context will be always `WS`:

```js
@Catch(WsException, HttpException)
export class WsAndHttpExceptionFilter {
  public catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    // Here you have the exception and you can check the data
    const ctx = host.switchToWs()
    const client = ctx.getClient() as WebSocket;
    client.send(JSON.stringify({ /* ... */ }))
  }
}
```

Or also you can try to create the `exceptionFactory` to return the `WsException`.

- Into the decorator:

```js
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({
    exceptionFactory(validationErrors: ValidationError[] = []) {
        // Here are the errors
        if (this.isDetailedOutputDisabled) {
          return new WsException();
        }
        const errors = this.flattenValidationErrors(validationErrors);
        return new WsException(errors);
    }
}))
```

Check how factories [are done into the project](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/95e096fbf6fb8a8b7eb9a74979fd13141f79b0a9/packages/common/pipes/validation.pipe.ts#L153) and how this code tries to follow the same way but returning `WsException`.

- Or in a class extending `ValidationPipe`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class WSValidationPipe extends ValidationPipe {
  createExceptionFactory() {
    return (validationErrors: ValidationError[] = []) {
        // Here are the errors
        if (this.isDetailedOutputDisabled) {
          return new WsException();
        }
        const errors = this.flattenValidationErrors(validationErrors);
        return new WsException(errors);
    }
  }
}
```

By the way, you can also `@Catch(WsException)` (and only this exception which is clearer) once are thrown if it is util for you to return the data you want:

```js
@Catch(WsException)
export class WebsocketExceptionsFilter extends BaseWsExceptionFilter { 
  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToWs()
    const client = ctx.getClient() as WebSocket;
    const data = ctx.getData();
    client.send(JSON.stringify({
      event: 'error',
      ok: false,
      error: exception.getError(),
      data: data  // Or whatever you want to add
    }))
  }
}
```

I can't test now all this code but I've used some of these snippets and works for me, hope it helps.

Comment: OMG, THANK YOU, YOU ARE TOP G, it helped!! as you mentioned,  I made `exceptionFactory`  throw new `WsException`  error  and then caught it in `WsExceptionFilter`. you helped me very much!!!

Comment: The data you return in the handler `    return { event: Stream.Transactions, data: req }
` may i pls know how to access it in the frontend ?